# Is there a way to distinguish pointer types in llvm ir?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to optimize codes in llvm ir, realizing that Types - isPointerTy does not distinguish between *i8, *i16, *i32, *i64. Printing out their type values obviously gives different values. Below is the code I used to detect the problem.

in C:

```
...
if (CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(UsrI)) {
   if (CI->getCalledFunction()->getReturnType() ->isPointerTy()){
      outs() << "Calling func with ptr return = " << CI->getCalledFunction()->getName() << "\n";
      outs() << CI->getCalledFunction()->getReturnType() << "\n";
   }
}
...
```

in llvm:

```
...
if.end:
    %test3 = call i64* @malloc64(i64 %mul)
    %call = call i32* @malloc32(i64 %mul) #4
    %test = call i16* @malloc16(i64 %mul)
    %test2 = call i8* @malloc8(i64 %mul)
...
declare i8* @malloc8(i64)
declare i16* @malloc16(i64)
declare i16* @malloc16(i64)
declare i16* @malloc16(i64)
```

Showing output as

> Calling func with ptr return = malloc8
>   0x1c56e90
>   Calling func with ptr return = malloc16
>   0x1c56e20
>   Calling func with ptr return = malloc32
>   0x1c56db0
>   Calling func with ptr return = malloc64
>   0x1c56d40

I tried checking through many llvm documents, but I have missed out something. Any advice on how I may check exact pointer type would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isPointerTy` method doesn't distinguish between different types, it just tells `true` or `false` whether a type is a pointer.

One way to resolve your issue is to look into it's underlying, *pointee* type (the type a pointer points to).

This is how you can do it:

```
Type *returnType = CI->getCalledFunction()->getReturnType();
if (PointerType *pointerType = dyn_cast<PointerType>(returnType)) {
  llvm::Type *pointeeType = pointerType->getElementType();
  /// the pointee type now holds one of i8, i16, i32, or i64
  if (IntegerType *intType = dyn_cast<IntegerType>(pointeeType)) {
    outs() << intType->getBitWidth() << "\n";
  }
}
```

The second line attempts to cast the general `Type *` to a more special `PointerType *`. The `dyn_cast` returns either a valid pointer or a `nullptr` if the `returnType` is not a `PointerType`.

Then, you get access to the pointee type (via `getElementType`) and can do further checks. In your example, all the underlying types are `IntegerType`s, the way to distinguish them is to check their bitwidth.

This should help, I guess :)